# Classify the singularities of the function

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=\frac{z^3+1}{z^2(z+1)} $$

has singularities $z=0, z=-1$  right?

How can I determine the type of singularity of this points?

**Classifications:**

1.)Removable pole (Then $f(z_0)$ is bounded, $f(z)$ has a limit if $z \to \infty$

2.) Pole of order $m \implies |f(z)|\to \infty $ as $z \to z_0$

3.) Essential singularity : not bounded, does not go to infinity.

(Another way to descibre is to look at the coefficients of the Laurent Series.

Comment: In some classes it is not really convered, so I'm curious: are you also expected to talk about the (possible) singularity at $z=\infty$?

Comment: That's the next paragraph :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function $f$ which is holomorphic for all $z$ near $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ (with $z \neq z_0$) has a pole of order $m>0$ at $z=z_0$ if and only if

$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^m f(z)
$$

is finite and nonzero.  If $f$ has a singularity at $z=z_0$ and

$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)
$$

is finite and nonzero then the singularity is removable, and vice versa.

Comment: How to apply this to my function?

Comment: @Joyeuse, consider the pole at $z=0$.  What $m$ must you choose to make $\lim_{z\to 0} z^m f(z)$ exist and be nonzero?

Comment: that would be 0...

Comment: @Joyeuse no... are you telling me that $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^3+1}{z^2(z+1)}$$ is finite?

Comment: I understand. It should be 2.

Comment: @Joyeuse right!  So your function has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$.  Then, using the factorization provided by [M. Strochyk](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/283720/5531) you can see that $\lim_{z\to -1} f(z) = 3$, so you have a removable singularity at $z=-1$.

Comment: thanks for your troublel. i appreciate it :-)

Comment: Glad to help! ${}$

Comment: By the way: If $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z) = 0$, can you then say that $z_0$ is a removable singularity? And what if $z_0$ is a zero too?

Comment: What I mean is: Can we say that a removable singulariy is equivalent to a 'pole of order 0'?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7203/discussion-between-joyeuse-saint-valentin-and-antonio-vargas)

Comment: @Joyeuse, you're right, I should have added the requirement that that limit be nonzero.  If the limit is zero then you have a zero of some multiplicity $m > 0$ which you can find by checking when $$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$$ is finite and nonzero.

Comment: @Joyeuse I don't know if the "pole of order $0$" wording is standard; you'd be better off just calling it a removable singularity.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Your statement in the answer is slightly incorrect. $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^m f(z)$ has to be finite, non-zero, and holomorphic

Comment: @johndoe the result of $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^m f(z)$ is not a function. Either it's a single complex number, it's $\infty$, or it doesn't exist. In what way would you want that to be holomorphic?

Answer (score 4):

Decompose $f$ as
$$f(z)=\dfrac{z^3+1}{z^2(z+1)}=\dfrac{(z+1)(z^2-z+1)}{z^2(z+1)}.$$
Then $f$ has at $z_0=-1$ removable singularity and pole of order $2$ at $z_1=0.$ What type of singularity is at $z^*=\infty$ ?

Comment: How can you see that the order of $z_1=0$ is $2$ so quickly? 

Is a removable singularity because of the cancelation? (Always the case?)

If $z$ goes to $\infty$ I think it has a limit ($f \to $1$ as $z \to \infty$). ?

Comment: As Antonio Vargas suggested, $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z^2 f(z)=\lim\limits_{z \to 0} (z^2-z+1)=1$ and
$\lim\limits_{z \to {-1},\;z\ne{-1}}  f(z)=3$

Answer (score 4):

By applying [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction), we get:
$$
f(z) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{z} + \dfrac{1}{z^2}
$$

It's now easy to see that $z = -1$ is a removable singularity. $z^3 + 1$ can be factored as $(z + 1)(z^2 - z + 1)$ so $z + 1$ can be canceled and this removes the singularity.

For the singularity at $z = 0$, it is a pole of order two as the principal part is clearly $- \dfrac{1}{z} + \dfrac{1}{z^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The exposition of @Ayman Hourieh simplifies the problem.

For visual reinforcement, conformal maps are presented where Re $z$ is blue, and Im $z$ is red. On the *left* is the input function
$$
 f(z) = \frac{z^{3} + 1}{z^{2}(z+1)} = 1 - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^{2}}
$$
On the *right* is the input function with the singularity suppressed
$$
 z^{2}f(z) = \frac{z^{3} + 1}{(z+1)} = z^{2} - z + 1
$$

[image: both]

#### Addendum

@nilo de roock and others have asked how to reproduce plots in Mathematica.

```
z := x + I y;
f[z_] := (z^3 + 1)/(z + 1);
\[Lambda] = 1;
pts = 100;
gre = ContourPlot[
   ComplexExpand[Re[f[z]]], {x, -\[Lambda], \[Lambda]}, {y, -\[Lambda], \[Lambda]}, 
   Contours -> 15, ContourShading -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.5]}}, PlotPoints -> pts];
```

Comment: These are Mathematica graphics, right? Which function did you use?